# Is there a deadlock in following situation and what could be the solution to prevent it?

Tags: c#, multithreading, logging, thread-safety, locking

I have a `FileLogger` class which logs messages to a txt file. My intention is to make the `FileLogger` class thread safe so that multiple threads could write log messages in a thread safe manner. I have a lock object to allow only one thread to write at a moment.

Also in the same application I have a `GlobalExceptionHandler` class which handles all expected and unexpected exceptions. The handling of exceptions is all about logging in a file. So, the `GlobalExceptionHandler` will eventually call `FileLogger` `Log` method to log to file. In terms of code it can be shown as:

```
class FileLogger {

  ...

  public void Log(string logOrigin, string message, LogLevel logLevel) {
    //some code
    lock (logWriteLock) {
        try {
          using (var logFileStream = File.Open(logFilePath, FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.Read)) {
            logFileStream.Write(messageBytes, 0, messageBytes.Length);
            logFileStream.Flush();
          }
        } catch (Exception ex) { 
          globalExceptionHandler.HandleException(ex);
        }
      }
  }

}

class GlobalExceptionHandler {

  public void HandleException(Exception ex) {
    //some code
    fileLogger.Log(...);
  }
}
```

**My understanding:**

The lock `logWriteLock` is acquired by the thread, then it tries to open the file and write to it. The happy scenario will be fine but if there is an exception while trying to write, then the control will go to `HandleException` method which will be executed by the same thread.The `HandleException` will again call `Log`. Since the thread already has the lock, it can reenter and then reattempt to write to file. This will go on and on.

Is my understanding correct? Or will the lock be released as soon as we hit the line `globalExceptionHandler.HandleException(ex)` (as we have reached the end of critical section and the method `HandleException` does not explicitly lock on `logWriteLock`)?

I have a gut feeling that I have circular references and deadlock will happen.

Also if there is a deadlock, then what could be the possible solution. Do we need an extra file just to log the exceptions in FileLogger (which i think is not a good idea as we lead to unnecessary complexity of design)?

Comment: Terms are somewhat off here, but your "gut feeling" is right. You may end up in an "infinite" loop. What you can do is handle this one specific exception _not_ through the globalExceptionHandler. But what I would suggest you rather do is not reinvent the wheel. Use a Logging-Framework.

Comment: @Fildor Yes I totally agree on not reinventing the wheel but i am under a restriction to not use one. Also not handling this specific exception through globalExceptionHandler beats the purpose to have one central place of exception handling.

Comment: You cannot have both :( It makes absolutely _no_ sense to have this handled by the global handler.

Comment: What a `Log` method should never do is to throw exceptions, or block the caller for an extensive amount of time. Your current approach seems to be destined for doing both!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Or will the lock be released as soon as we hit the line
>   globalExceptionHandler.HandleException(ex) (as we have reached the end
>   of critical section and the method HandleException does not explicitly
>   lock on logWriteLock)?

You are still inside the lock section, doesn't matter the level of depth you get into when calling methods from lock section.

So you will loop inside forever while holding the lock. 
When logging fails, there is no reason to try to log exception as it will probably fail too. So either have another kind of logger or send the notification so you can react when such a problem occurs.